# Problems with getters and setters

Tags: java

I have a problem with getters and setters, so I set the object list in one class Users object list and I use the getter in the second class and when I run the debugger the getter returns Null despite the fact that when I set the setter in the first class list with one object. What i'm doing wrong?

```
public class Aplication extends Controller {
    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());
    @FXML
    private ListView<String> contacts;
    @FXML
    private Label nameContact;
    @FXML
    private TextField myMessage;
    @FXML
    private TextArea Message;
    @FXML
    private Label limitText;
    @FXML
    private Label startowyLabel;



    private List<Users> contactList;
    private static Client client;
    public static boolean online = false;
    private final Stage win =Main.getWindow();
    public void pustaLista() {
        ObservableList<String> data = contacts.getItems();
        if (data.isEmpty()) {
            ObservableList<String> newData = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Kontakty są puste");
            contacts.setItems(newData);
        }
    }
    public static void close(){
        client.sendMessage(new ChatMessage(ChatMessage.LOGOUT, ""));
    }

    public List<Users> getContactList() {
        return contactList;
    }
    public void setContactList(List<Users> contactList) {
        this.contactList = contactList;
    }

    public void kontakty() {
        List<String> list;
        List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
        Contacts contact = new Contacts(logintext);
        DBI db = new DB();

        try {
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(Constants.JDBC_URL, Constants.JDBC_USERNAME, Constants.JDBC_PASSWORD);
            list = db.readCon(connection, contact);
            for (String s : list) {
                Users user = new Users(s);
                list2.add(db.findUser(connection, user));
            }
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Couldn't connect to database", e);
        }
        if (list2.isEmpty()) {
            pustaLista();
        } else {
            List<Users> users1 = new ArrayList<>();
            for(String s: list2){
                String[] res = s.split(" ");
                Users users = new Users();
                users.setNickname(logintext);
                users.setFistName(res[0]);
                users.setLastName(res[1]);
                users1.add(users);
                System.out.println(users.getLastName());
                setContactList(users1);
                System.out.println(users1.toString());
            }
            ObservableList<String> observableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(list2);
            contacts.setItems(observableList);
        }


    }

    public void wyszukaj() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(this.getClass().getResource("search.fxml"));
        Pane pane = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Wyszukiwanie");
        stage.getIcons().clear();
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image(this.getClass().getResource("search.png").toString()));
        stage.show();
    }

    public void update() {
        int dl = myMessage.getText().length();
        limitText.setText(dl + "/1000");
    }
    void append(String mess){
        if(Message.getText() != null) {
            Message.setText(Message.getText() + mess);
        } else {
            Message.setText(mess);
        }
    }
    public String autor() {
        DBI db = new DB();
        String res = "";
        Users users = new Users(Controller.logintext);
        try {
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(Constants.JDBC_URL, Constants.JDBC_USERNAME, Constants.JDBC_PASSWORD);
            res = db.findUser(connection, users);
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
        }
        return res;
    }
    public void createGroup() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(this.getClass().getResource("groups.fxml"));
        Pane pane = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Wybranie osób do grupy");
        stage.getIcons().clear();
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image(this.getClass().getResource("group.png").toString()));
        stage.show();
    }
    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        kontakty();
        client = new Client("localhost", 1500, autor(), this);
        win.setOnCloseRequest(e->{
            e.consume();
            Main.closeProgram();
        });
        if(!client.start())
            return;
        myMessage.setOnKeyPressed(e-> {
            if(e.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)){

                client.sendMessage(new ChatMessage(ChatMessage.MESSAGE, myMessage.getText()));
                myMessage.setText("");
            }
        });
        myMessage.setOnKeyReleased(e -> {
            if(e.getCode() != KeyCode.ENTER)
                update();
        });
        contacts.setOnMouseClicked(mouseEvent -> {
            nameContact.setVisible(true);
            myMessage.setVisible(true);
            Message.setVisible(true);
            limitText.setVisible(true);
            online = true;
            startowyLabel.setVisible(false);
            nameContact.setText(contacts.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
            limitText.setText("0/1000");
        });
    }

}
```

class one

```
public class Groups extends Aplication{
    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());

    public List<Users> getlC() {
        return lC;
    }

    public void setlC(List<Users> lC) {
        this.lC = lC;
    }

    @FXML
    private ListView<String> lv;
    private List<Users> lC;
    public void choise(){
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Users users : getlC()) {
            list.add(users.getFistName() + " " + users.getLastName() + " " + users.getNickname());
        }
        System.out.println(lC.toString());
        System.out.println(list.toString());
        ObservableList<String> observableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(list);
        lv.setItems(observableList);
    }
    @FXML
    void initialize(){
        List<Users> lU = getContactList();
        setlC(lU);
        choise();
    }
}
```

class two

```
 for(String s: list2){
                String[] res = s.split(" ");
                Users users = new Users();
                users.setNickname(logintext);
                users.setFistName(res[0]);
                users.setLastName(res[1]);
                users1.add(users);
                System.out.println(users.getLastName());
                setContactList(users1);
                System.out.println(users1.toString());
            }
```

Normally returned data here

```
 List<Users> lU = getContactList();
```

Returned NullPointer

Comment: your code is not reproducable

Comment: I get the feeling that you  are calling the setter in an instance of class A and getter in an instance of class B and somehow expect that to work, but without minimal  reproducible  example I cannot say for certain what is going on.

Comment: You should not use images, and you *should* include the full code (reduced to [mcve]) **in the question** - not in links to other sites.

Comment: the code has been placed

Comment: As per @RealSkeptic's comment, all code should be posted as code-formatted text, not as a link to a code repository. It's not easy to ask a well-received question on this site, but by following our advice and by checking out the [help] link, you will get the hang of it soon. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

First of all - I love how some of your code is in English and some of it is in Polish. This is a very bad habit that will bite you in the ass if you ever work with an international team. Not to mention it’s harder for people on SO or in other places to help you if they do not understand method or variable names.

Second - why are those two lines:

```
setContactList(users1);
System.out.println(users1.toString());
```

inside the loop? It would make more sense for them to be executed after the loop is finished.

And finally - the root of your problem. This method:

```
void initialize(){
    List<Users> lU = getContactList();
    setlC(lU);
    choise();
}
```

throws `NullPointerException` because field `contactList` is in fact null. That field is initialized by method `kontakty()` from class `Application`, which is called by `initialize()` method of the same class. However neither of those methods are called anywhere in class `Groups`.

Unless there is some JavaFX magic happening that I do not know about, `initialize()` method in class `Groups` should be:

```
void initialize(){
       kontakty();
       List<Users> lU = getContactList();
       setlC(lU);
       choise();
    }
```

or possibly even:

```
void initialize(){
    super.initialize()
    List<Users> lU = getContactList();
    setlC(lU);
    choise();
}
```

if you want all the initialization code from the superclass to be executed in the subclass as well.

Comment: Sout is is for testing only and i know that setter need to be outside the loop and  i know the loop how many times it will be done

Comment: ```
void initialize(){
       kontakty();
       List<Users> lU = getContactList();
       setlC(lU);
       choise();
    }
```
anyway returned nulls

Comment: That makes no sense unless `list2` is empty.